# Trying to load a csv in jupyter and giving error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 49: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I was just trying to load a csv into jupyter and got the error message below

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 49: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0):

You have non-unicode characters in the CSV. Try passing the encoding parameter, usually for latin languages you need to use encoding = "latin-1"